# Ajax getJSON data to change rotate transform value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have the following code to get JSON data

```
    $.getJSON('ajax.php', function(data) {
    });
```

The JSON data looks like this:

```
{"hour":"180","min":"270","sec":"30"}
```

I can alert hour, min or sec like this:

```
alert(data.hour);
```

However, I want to use the value from data.hour to change a rotation / transform css value. I tried the following but doesn't seem to work

```
    $.getJSON('ajax.php', function(data) {
        $('#clock .hh').css( {'transform': 'rotate(data.hour+'deg')'});
    });
```

I even tried to change the JSON file to this:

```
{"hour":"180deg","min":"270deg","sec":"30deg"}
```

And then tried this:

```
        $('#clock .hh').css( {'transform': 'rotate(data.hour)'});
```

But even this did not work

Any ideas how this can be done?

Comment: Your `data.hour` in the css() call is text, it is not the variable

Comment: @Patrick Evans I tried $('#clock .hh').css( {'transform': 'rotate(data.hour)'}); and for the hour value in the JSON file i put 180deg but even that did not work

Comment: @Ahmed you need the quotes to disting the variable from the string like this `$('#clock .hh').css( {'transform': 'rotate('+data.hour+')'}); `

Comment: @Ahmed check [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-work-with-strings-in-javascript) to understand better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have a typo error in you code.
There's no quotes between `data.hour` to seperate it from the string
Here's the correction

```
$.getJSON('ajax.php', function(data) {
        $('#clock .hh').css( {'transform': 'rotate('+data.hour+'deg)'});
    });
```

After your edit
you should just write

```
$('#clock .hh').css( {'transform': 'rotate('+data.hour+')'});
```

Answer (score 0):

The formatting of the code snippet almost reveals what I think is the problem:

```
'transform': 'rotate(data.hour+'deg')'
```

"data.hour" is treated as string value here, not as the actual value.

Try this:

```
'transform': 'rotate(' + data.hour + 'deg')'
```